# Is it possible to cross reference FB taggable_friends and local user records under API v2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am using Koala in a Rails app to get a user's friends for a simple tagging interface.

Some time back, Facebook changed the API (v2.0) such that this end point now returns a hashed ID, rather than the friend's FB ID. I've just started working with this endpoint for the first time since the change and am wondering, is it still possible to correlate an FB taggable_friends with a user of my app.

For example, within my app a user creates an event she attended, and now wants to tag friends she was with. The taggable_friends API allows taggings to be pushed to FB, but how do I also represent that tagging within my app?

The `taggable_friends` endpoint returns basic details such as name and avatar, so I could just store and display those. But if the friend is also a user of my app, and perhaps has a different avatar here, I'd like to display the details they have set in the app rather than FB details.

Is there any way to cross reference taggable_friends with local user records under the new API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tagging token is not valid forever, so you cannot cross-reference users. It would only be possible by name, but that is not reliable since users can change their name or two users can have the exact same one.

In other words: No, it is not possible.

Comment: thanks luschn, that's what I was afraid of. FB has made it very difficult to integrate their platform into an app's existing user tagging.